# 'to treat vs to handle vs to deal with'

Tags: word-choice

After searching in dictionaries, I have found that the phrasal verb **'deal with'** **is informal** and its formal equivalent can be, among others, **'to handle'**. However, when I searched for the verb **'to treat',** I did not find any reference saying that the verb is informal (in Oxford Thesaurus of English, Pocket Oxford American Dictionary, and Chambers Universal Learners' Dictionary...they all consider it **formal/neutral**).

though I think it would be very informal to say **in academic writing** (as am writing an academic disssertation) **'to treat the situation'** instead of **'to handle/or to manage the situation'.** I think it is informal to be used academically. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

I think that saying *to treat the situation* is not idiomatic; it isn't something a native speaker would say. *To handle the situation* sounds much better. *To deal with* and *to manage the situation* are also fine.

Now that I have thought about it again, I feel that there is a subtle difference between *handling a situation/dealing with a situation* and *managing a situation*. *Handling/dealing with a situation* give more of a sense of fixing the situation while *managing a situation* sounds like you are just trying to make sure it doesn't get any worse.

Also I don't agree that *to deal with* is more informal than *to handle*. You can use both interchangeably.

Comment: "treat" also carries with it a suggestion of treating an injury or illness

Answer (score 0):

The sentences

```
    To treat the situation with care.

    To handle the situation carefully.

    To deal with the situation adroitly.
```

are all valid.  I wouldn't consider one to be less suitable in an academic paper than the others.